# PowerShell - Add-Content- Unable to add multiple vars to a file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to add an expression to a log file which contains Date,Time some data separated by ";". Unfortunately I get an error every time I change the position of the items in the -value brackets.

Whats seems to be wrong?

This is the code :

```
Add-Content -path C:\...\outlog.txt -Value($Date + ';' + $Time + ';Checked;' + $strFileName)
```

This is the error :

```
Cannot convert argument "1", with value: ";", for "op_Addition" to type "System.TimeSpan": "Cannot convert 
value ";" to type "System.TimeSpan". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan.""
At C:\...\Untitled1.ps1:8 char:64
+ ... \outlog.txt -Value($($Date + ';' + $Time + ';'+ $str))
+                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
Add-Content -path C:\...\outlog.txt -Value("$Date; $Time; Checked; $strFileName")
```

If you look at `get-help Add-Content -full`, and look at the `-value` parameter, you will see -

```
-Value <Object[]>
    Specifies the content to be added. Type a quoted string, such as "This data is for internal use only", or
    specify an object that contains content, such as the DateTime object that Get-Date generates.

    You cannot specify the contents of a file by typing its path, because the path is just a string, but you can
    use a Get-Content command to get the content and pass it to the Value parameter.

    Required?                    true
    Position?                    1
    Default value                None
    Accept pipeline input?       True (ByPropertyName, ByValue)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

It says that it expects a `quoted string` or an `object that contains content`. It was missing in your case and hence the `+` operator was trying to add `$date` and `time`.

Comment: You are welcome. You would want to accept the proposed solution, if it has successfully solved your problem. It would help others who witness a similar scenario and would encourage us folks to answer other questions. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for info.

Comment: Or use the string format operator `-value ("{0};{1};Checked;{2}" -f $Date,$Time,$strFileName)`

Comment: @LotPings - True! That will also do.

Comment: @LotPings Great idea!